# How could the path to an include file cause different behaviour/warnings from g++?

Tags: c++

If I compile with g++ -Itemp I get a warning but if I compile without -Itemp I get no warning.

I have triple checked that the three header files in /temp/exodus are identical to those in /usr/local/include/exodus.

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra  -std=c++2a -c /root/exodus/test/src/test_MB.cpp -H -Itemp

g++ -Wall -Wextra  -std=c++2a -c /root/exodus/test/src/test_MB.cpp -H
```

Here is a diff of the output (-H to verify the header include locations).

```
07:20:08 root@de1:~/exodus/test/src# diff temp_warning usr_local_include --color=always
13,14c13,14
< . temp/exodus/program.h
< .. temp/exodus/exodus.h
---
> . /usr/local/include/exodus/program.h
> .. /usr/local/include/exodus/exodus.h
244c244
< ... temp/exodus/exomacros.h
---
> ... /usr/local/include/exodus/exomacros.h
248,261d247
< In file included from temp/exodus/exodus.h:39,
<                  from temp/exodus/program.h:3,
<                  from /root/exodus/test/src/test_MB.cpp:4:
< /root/exodus/test/src/test_MB.cpp: In member function ‘exodus::var ExodusProgram::test_ioconv(exodus::ExodusProgramBase::in, exodus::ExodusProgramBase::in)’:
< temp/exodus/exomacros.h:124:12: warning: logical not is only applied to the left hand side of comparison [-Wlogical-not-parentheses]
<   124 | #define eq ==
<       |            ^~
< /root/exodus/test/src/test_MB.cpp:14:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘eq’
<    14 |  if (not ovar.iconv("MB") eq ivar)
<       |                           ^~
< /root/exodus/test/src/test_MB.cpp:14:6: note: add parentheses around left hand side expression to silence this warning
<    14 |  if (not ovar.iconv("MB") eq ivar)
<       |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<       |      (                   )
```

Comment: Do the `temp` directory have a duplicate header file that is included, and defines `eq` (which is really a bad macro!) differently?

Comment: As for the warning itself, have you *read* it? The logical not operator `not` (or `!`) have higher [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than comparison for equality `==`. So the expression `not ovar.iconv("MB") eq ivar` is really the same as `(not ovar.iconv("MB")) eq ivar`, which is likely not what you want.

Comment: The warning does indeed indicate an error in the code. Which is exactly why am determined to find out why a different path location for the include file results in no warning.

Comment: The temp/exodus dir has only three files and they are identical to those in /usr/local/include/exodus. I triple checked the files size, date and contents. The diff proves exactly what header files are used with and without -Itemp.

Comment: I think gcc ignores some warnings from system libraries

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html

Comment: @AlanBirtles `-I` does not add *system* headers

Comment: @n.m. yes but the place where the warnings are missing isn't using `-I` it's a default include path

Comment: @AlanBirtles Indeed, this must be the reason. /usr/local/include is a system header directory.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Strictly, it's  a prioritized include path, not default one. now default directory is `-iquote`, kind of. Default include path is current path (i.e. path of  folder containing .cpp file) for gcc, -I prohibits use of current directory as first go-to, while `-iquote` expands lookup.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Adding -I/usr/local/include to the compile command also results in no warning. It seems that my Ubuntu 20/04 g++9 compiler is compiled to ignore all warnings triggered by macros in that dir as per your link gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html

Comment: @Abazoo `-I` doesn't override `-isystem` behavior, because `-isystem` > `-I`, it would look there first. On other hand `-isystem temp` would disable warnings

Answer (score 1):

It's platform-defined, but most likely when you use `-isystem` to point at headers instead of `-I` or use `#pragma GCC system_header` in header, your flavor of gcc environment would suppress the warning out of erroneous reasoning - it  does not refer to entities from "system" headers, so it really can't output this:

```
< temp/exodus/exomacros.h:124:12: warning: logical not is only applied to the left hand side of comparison [-Wlogical-not-parentheses]
<   124 | #define eq ==
```

From online docs:

> Macros defined in a system header are immune to a few warnings
> wherever they are expanded.